# How to change the audio track in Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-7, audio, windows-media-player

I have some movie files which have audio in 4 languages.

I can change the audio track to any language in MX and VLC in android and KM player in windows.

I tried to do it in Windows Media Player in Windows 7 but can't find an option for that.

How to change the audio track of a video file in windows media player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I change the audio track of a video file in windows media player?

This is done from the Classic Menu.

> Unfortunately switching audio tracks is one of those features buried
>   in the new interface.  You have to bring up the "classic" menu like
>   so:
>
> 1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> to view the "default menu" (you can also right-click to the right or left of the audio controls, but
>      "show menu bar" does not show in Now Playing mode).
> 2. Select "Play" > "Audio and language tracks".
> 3. Select the audio track you would like to play.
> 4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to remove the menu.

[image]

Source [How to Switch Audio Tracks in Windows Media Player](http://www.ocmodshop.com/how-to-switch-audio-tracks-in-windows-media-player/)